# split to get array,object in string

Tags: javascript, regex

While learning JavaScript, i use split but not working ,with json result

```
[\"a\",\"b\"]","[]","[]","{"userEmail": "abc@gmail.com", "password": "AFds@42"}
```

Please explain I am screwed up here.

i want to result

```
[ [\"a\",\"b\"],[],[],{"userEmail": "abc@gmail.com", "password": "AFds@42"} ]
```

```js
var str= '[\"a\",\"b\"]","[]","[]","{"userEmail": "abc@gmail.com", "password": "AFds@42"}';
str.split(songthing)
```

Comment: You are missing `)` which is the reason for error. But ideally you should be using `JSON.parse` method to convert the JSON string to object and then access the properties. Not regex.

Comment: Regular expressions cannot match potentially infinitely-nested patterns. This means that using a regex to parse a JSON string is brittle. (Meaning it will certainly break under various circumstances.) Use `JSON.parse`. It’s safer, more maintainable, and clearer. In general you should get data out of strings and into familiar, workable data types as soon as you can.

Comment: @Boney thanks you but it is example,  my regex very bad, iwant result 
[ [\"a\",\"b\"],[],[],{"userEmail": "abc@gmail.com", "password": "AFds@42"} ] after use regex or something do work